# Recursively generating keyed type for a const tree-like structure

Tags: typescript

I have a constant tree-like object to model nested relations and am trying to build a type that keys these relations by a fixed property of the parent object; i.e. I want to take this:

```js
const tree = {
    label: 'root',
    leaves: [
        {
            label: 'root.a',
        },
        {
            label: 'root.b',
            leaves: [
                {
                    label: 'root.b.a',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            label: 'root.c',
            leaves: [
                {
                    label: 'root.c.a',
                },
                {
                    label: 'root.c.b',
                    leaves: [
                        {
                            label: 'root.c.b.a',
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
} as const
```

and infer a literal type like this:

```js
type KeyedTree = {
  "root.a": {},
  "root.b": {
    "root.b.a": {}
  },
  "root.c": {
    "root.c.a": {},
    "root.c.b": {
      "root.c.b.a": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Sample code of what I tried so far: [TypeScript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDsHsBMFNQC4E8AOsDOAoZbQBlYBDAM1AF5QBvUAG0ICNYaAuUdBAJwEtwBzAGlpEAbhgD8rAEpFokcDSQAeAiQDaAXQB8oAL7ZU8ACodY8CitIAyKkMKj0UmXIXKixDdr2YQoAMZz2QnAERBN4dg4AV18ESJNMf3B2UNNyKkxQTNoGJlYAcg5ISAQ8-gysmhEMVlVyrKzKOvrmukYWUAKihAA6QlKm+p0y5oaBkey2-MLi7vp+8Zaqh1BahYXGtc2J3I7pnvpe+a3B4a31U5GhscyNrdadzpnfI83Ku2qV67Xb45H79sePV8hwuvyuv1GEL+OQBe26wLmoKhtnsNS+yJ+yLW-ymXXhsxB6Kh4KxmXORMuSPG5IWJLJZR0oEI6D8AQQmG8YE4QXQxEgHAAtoQEFw5IhIKAANawJCwaCIAz6XAAaRlcosaQA8gKuAhXCRBHl-nlNEr4HgYehFIZQLAAB4IWDgaAs4ymbQUQyqI1LPLqVTgSICxgcf1GmF+s2gACyhCQjDdsGttodTpd+DcHtANvtjudrrCTTEoFVsugGus0n8HGgykt1s0glL6szTVY2t1imb5bchre9hNHJ8viCoB4xFgHAgMFgAFp6EhZ1A4KBZ6AABaQADu4pT3JioAARN3E4eFbhoFwTDEFKBiIUBSl4Il2GIo5IugBBNKx+OwROKAAFDgsCQKQnCmAAlN6-YYH6qgAAxaO+XQAEI-nGCZhEBIFgU+0E+u86DwQAjMhIGgB+xQAMIYX+AHAQYeEQbABGwcR-oAEzkQYlFdNR34UL+WGmDhTHgWEbG+lxYbsfBSGmhRVEINR6FCZh-7YYxaDMZJMHSao3H6URpE8bgymqYJMYaQxuESVBxkDjJjlwf6ZEuRxiHIZyoBbkEIQIBKhAoCgt7CZpqTXnE6BcKIt6BWO4ATlOCDrlwLIgVGJ5hGkmJ7KwmL1IChwFUMxw+Mpn5fMVcwFRCFVoUSNUlVQZXjA1xSoVVtJUpkxXPHVvwdSpFK7HiwJ9KVgjNMNAm9c0-WzHkg0jLNqGjUVcIIi1lCMmtn7zScXx0roDJDmA3SXbA3S8N0zCYMQkTgDEorgKAQr0WEgHLrArCJqAAA+GYkJB6SZFwpDfTO3TsaDeWwLEHBvT9MNLN0JjQNEsCAWMwFhIIP2g2Q2iAZQl3dCxggBtD-zqKwH0idjhM6JBVK7U0kHlIyTDoPA8OI297OZHoXgvpAlQw5AvCAQzEXYyxkGc8AABUmCqHgmoAOJ02DR5woQh5TeUh5wvQhu65kJt4gcBulVzpxW085uYo7QK9M7J2u-iZsFWMXvbbbrVNHowuYHoyvAEAA)

I managed to get types working that test if a particular node contains children, and if so, yields a `Record` type with the correct string literal keys, but I am struggling to extend this to traverse the full object to capture the nested structure (and iterating over the nodes rather than using hardcoded references to the indices).

I feel like it should be as simple as recursively applying the `MaybeTree` type across the child nodes (see bottom of playground link for example at runtime) - but I have not been able to find a way to translate this into the typing system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets give the type of `tree` something we can use as a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints):

```
type Tree = { label: string; leaves?: readonly Tree[] };
```

Then we can write a recursive `ToKeyedTree<T>` utility type that turns an input `T extends Tree` into the form you want, like this:

```
type ToKeyedTree<T extends Tree> =
    T["leaves"] extends readonly Tree[] ? {
        [L in T["leaves"][number] as L["label"]]: ToKeyedTree<L>
    } : {}
```

The approach here is to use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to iterate over the element types `L` of `T`'s `leaves` property, assuming it exists (we use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to check that and return `{}` if it doesn't exist).  For each such element `L`, we want to add a property with key `L["label"]` and with value `ToKeyedTree<L>`.

---

Let's make sure it works with your example:

```
type KeyedTree = ToKeyedTree<typeof tree>;
/* type KeyedTree = {
    "root.a": {};
    "root.b": {
        "root.b.a": {};
    };
    "root.c": {
        "root.c.a": {};
        "root.c.b": {
            "root.c.b.a": {};
        };
    };
} */
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIBUBO04F5YG9YBsCGAjabALlgGdREBLAOwHMBuHaXAN2jIH5TlcATAPY1s4BMmgBtALqwAvgxAQYCAQGlo4aHyQoAPPFjQAHqGg0+ZMSgB8sVMFiOEEgETYW7Mi5nHT5y7yCwqI6kjKcmA5O0RIAMrC0zm4eHN4SNACuALaEiFK4lrGueITY3lKk8GoaWqG6sdZRjrKwpBiyIADGQhSwlCh2kdElRKQA5IgCAqBjADRNzGwcpBIL0Rhr0U4jJLATU6AAdLhzm83zW04bl5c745PTh-inN1vuS2QrZ69DP393eweR3wxxefy2sgu4KkUMukO+13BAP2j06YP+KU+sFW4K2iNxtwIo0BB0OnVBsIJ8IJV2+uORQLJT3RNO2mK+rJ++M5PwZpPJIJOlJ5TmpItgMLpNzFf0lrxlEvmLQKsG6NAoYCgcHUmm04kGVR1tXEuiU0AEADM+uJrAoAPQAKj6WtgRr1A3Q3JcjNwLja8gW3tJ+D9v0uQcegtD7QU0QD0QjR060e+iaZvv9sZuaYFKdxOaex2j8elWeaChaDrtICAA)